# Are python packages version specific?

Tags: python

I ma trying to install https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-epo-ops-client
I tried installing it from pip from both latest version.

python 2.7.12 and 
python 3.5.2

for both of the version it says

```
C:\Users\me>pip install python-epo-ops-client 2.1.0
Collecting python-epo-ops-client
  Using cached python_epo_ops_client-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting 2.1.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 2.1.0 (from versions:
)
No matching distribution found for 2.1.0
```

As I am completely new to python, question is:

1) Do I need to install all python version to see which version above module is compatible with?
Or

2) can I know which version of python will be compatible with above version?

I want to install python for above package only. please suggest.

Comment: What is the **full output** of the command you used to try and install this?

Comment: Ok. Let me run it again and get back.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Please check the updated question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ravi: I don't know why but when I dropped the version number it did installed fine. pip install python-epo-ops-client for both version of pip

Comment: that's because ravi is actually correct; you didn't use the right syntax. You tried to install a *package named `2.1.0`* because you should have used `==2.1.0` to pin the version.

Comment: Thanks. Like NPM, PIP should also state on every module how to install the module for absolute beginners like me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having space between **python-epo-ops-client** & **2.1.0**, so it is trying to install two packages.

(1) python-epo-ops-client and 
(2) 2.1.0, but there isn't any package named "2.1.0"

To install specific version you need to mention **==**.

```
pip install python-epo-ops-client==2.1.0
```

Comment: Thanks man. I figured out but this has given me right information.